# Can I retrieve a deleted Cloud Page and Collection from Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Is there a way to retrieve deleted collection or resource from the web Studio?

Comment: There is not a way. Support may be able to restore the page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support CAN roll-back your SFMC instance up to a certain point, but this also rolls back other changes made since that time (unless things have changed on their process in the last 6 months).   To EazyE's point, there is not a native 'trash bin' for cloudpages.